# AutoLayout TableView issue with iPhone 6 and 6 Plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have 7 labels on a cell in `TableView` in Landscape mode and I have set the `Top Space` and `Leading Space` on each. My issue is it is working fine with iPhone 5 screen it fit well but I get and empty space with iPhone 6 and 6 Plus screen on the right place. How I can fix that with the constraint?

Example:
iPhone 5:
[image]
iPhone 6

### [image]

[image]

Comment: post your constraints and view hierarchy

Comment: @Bhavin you want all labels constraints?

Comment: No. I just want to know how I can give more spacing to some labels when the the screen become bigger? @Bhavin

Comment: ya but how can i imagine without any constraints....which size class are you using for constraints?

Comment: Do you have horizontal spacing between the label on the far right and the last label on the left? There should be no constraints between these two labels.

Comment: @Bhavin I will write to you the constraints. I'm using (wAny hCompact). No I didn't use pinned content view with edges.

Comment: than pinned content view...

Comment: I have add another image @Bhavin which may help

Comment: I think you doesn't pinned to right side of the last label

Comment: @Bhavin I have applied Trailing Space to Container Margin to the last label but it didn't work until I pinned the fourth label and it changed the last three labels to the right and fill the empty space. How can I change the spacing? Multiplier value won't effect while relation is Less Than or Equal.

Comment: I would suggest you to 1.) Add Trailing constraint to the last label in the cell   and do not add any width constraint on it. 2.)  Set a background color for testing so that you know how much space it is occupying in screen 3.) Add text Alignments to labels and set for the last label Center_Alignment or Right_Aligment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this youtube link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTMpJJ9Ofm8

In this link it is showing how to arrange vertical spacing.

You can apply same logic to "Trailing Space to Container Margin"  for equal spacing. By changing the multiplier value of the constraint you can change the spacing.

Comment: I've watched this video but I couldn't make it. Trailing Space to Container Margin to the last label but it didn't work until I pinned the fourth label and it changed the last three labels to the right and fill the empty space. How can  I change the spacing as I want while I've changed multiplier value but it won't change. relation is Less Than or Equal.